# ¿Cómo detectar correctamente pulsaciones sobre un listview?

Tags: android, listview

Tengo un listview personalizado con varios items. Cuando se llena de items la pantalla deslizo para ver los otros items pero al pulsar sobre estos items detecta mal las pulsaciones. Pulso un item después de bajar la lista y en un toast que coloqué dice que pulse el primero de la lista. ¿Cómo puedo evitar que esto ocurra?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el codigo que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: La variable position indica el indice del elemento, agregue una respuesta @gersonolivares

Answer (score 1):

Implementa `OnItemClickListener()` y mediante el método `onItemClick()` puedes detectar el clic.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

Log.d("ListView", "Se pulso el elemento en posición " + position);

            }
        });
```

Recuerda que `position` es en realidad el indice del elemento en el `ListView.`